# Why won't Log.i work?

Tags: java, android

Here's my code. I want to make sure that `randomNumber` remains the same until the user chooses the right number, so I'm trying to display that number via Log.i. However, whenever my button is clicked, nothing is printed to the android monitor.

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 1;

public void checkNumber(View view) {
    Log.i("Number", Integer.toString(randomNumber));
    EditText numberEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEntered);
    int numberEnteredInt = Integer.parseInt(numberEntered.getText().toString());
    if(!(numberEnteredInt <= 50 && numberEnteredInt >= 1)) {
        //some code
    } else if(numberEnteredInt < randomNumber) {
        //some code
    } else if(numberEnteredInt > randomNumber) {
        //some code
    } else {
        //some code
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    }
}
```

Just by running this app multiple times, it seems that the rest of my code is working properly (so I don't actually need Log to work in this case), but I am curious why nothing is being displayed to the monitor. Thanks.

Update:
Ok, now it's working perfectly; I don't know what was happening before. I noticed a couple of you recommended using "" + randomNumber instead of Integer.toString(randomNumber). Is the former more efficient? Thanks again.

Comment: Have you called checkNumber method anywhere?

Comment: @kapsym No. Do I need to?

Comment: Oh wait. I entered checkNumber for onClick for my button so it would be run whenever someone clicked the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you even need to use the Integer.toString() at all. You can just replace that whole line with:

```
Log.i("NUMBER", "" + randomNumber);
```

If you are calling the checkNumber() method as the onClick for the button, it should absolutely be printing to the console. Make sure your console is set to DEBUG mode, and that the line above the printouts doesn't read "No debuggable applications", but instead says the name of your app.

Comment: Is using the method you mentioned more efficient than Integer.toString()? I remember reading somewhere that string concatenation can be a burden in memory usage since it creates a new String object every time it is used. I just want to make sure I choose the right one in the future. Thanks.

Comment: For most things, it wouldn't be a big deal. Unless you're concatenating a bunch of things together. With just one variable being added, it's pretty negligible how long it will take. However, you are absolutely right that using an empty string and concatenation is slower than using toString(). But toString() is also slower than using StringBuilder, which is the most efficient way, but for something like this, could be considered overkill.
Here's a great article outlining all of the options you have:http://java-performance.info/primitive-types-to-string-conversion-and-string-concatenation/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure checkNumber() is called in your onClickListener? If so, try adding \n to the Log message.

```
    Log.i("Number", "\n" + randomNumber);
```

Comment: `toString()` is not needed.